# How to transpose arrays inside an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array of arrays that represent matrices and I need to transpose each matrix, ideally without transposing in a loop. When I use array.T, it transposes everything, not just the axes in each array. Is it possible to just transpose each matrix?

```
INPUT: np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3).T
OUTPUT:
[[[ 0  9 18]
  [ 3 12 21]
  [ 6 15 24]]

 [[ 1 10 19]
  [ 4 13 22]
  [ 7 16 25]]

 [[ 2 11 20]
  [ 5 14 23]
  [ 8 17 26]]]
```

What I want is for the arrays to look like this:

```
[[[ 0 3 6]
  [ 1 4 7]
  [ 2 5 8]]

 [[ 9 12 15]
  [ 10 13 16]
  [ 11 14 17]]

 [[ 18 21 24]
  [ 19 22 25]
  [ 20 23 26]]]
```

Comment: Use `a.transpose(2,0,1)`. Also, the last block seems wrong.

Comment: I just fixed it. That yields a first matrix of [[0, 3, 6], [9, 12, 15], [18, 21, 26]], which isn't the per-array transpose I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [11]: A = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
In [12]: A
Out[12]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

transpose the last 2 dimensions:

```
In [13]: A.transpose(0,2,1)
Out[13]: 
array([[[ 0,  3,  6],
        [ 1,  4,  7],
        [ 2,  5,  8]],

       [[ 9, 12, 15],
        [10, 13, 16],
        [11, 14, 17]],

       [[18, 21, 24],
        [19, 22, 25],
        [20, 23, 26]]])
```

`A.swapaxes(1,2)` also does it.

Comment: Wow, I've played around with the axes for the transpose and somehow neither came across that combo nor thought to try it... Thanks for answering! How the transpose describe the 3-D array may have also just now clicked for me.